# How to add post parameters to $.ajax and $.ajaxSubmit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used the ajax method of jquery for my forms. but now I need to add a field to the function.

how can I have my forms fields and my new post parameter.

```
        var frm = $(n);
        $.ajax({
                type: frm.attr('method'),
                url: frm.attr('action'),
                //contentType:frm.attr('enctype'),
                data: frm.serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    $(dataform).html(data);
                    $(des).html('');
                    $("button[type='submit']").attr('disabled',null);
                }
        });
```

the `data` parameter should be like this:

```
data: frm.serialize() + {'foo':'bar'}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: What problem you faced using frm.serialize() function?

Comment: I thought serialize() is really serialize the parameters. problem solved :)

Comment: Mark Question as Solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.serialize()` returns a string of parameters like you'd see in a querystring, so just add on `+ "&foo=bar"`

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
data: frm.serialize()+'&foo=bar',
```